# Implement mat-select with multiple choice in Form Array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a form component with dynamic groups of fields. A group field has only one field - mat-select with multiple choice. From the backend comes a list of options for the select.
The logic of the fields - when adding a new group in the list of options of the newly added select, the options selected in the previous group should be disabled for selection.

For example, in group 1, select option 1 in the mat-select. Next, add another group. In the mat-select of the second group, option 1 in the list of options should be disabled.
Let's add another group. In the list of options of this group, options 1 and 2 selected earlier should be disabled for choice.

When changing the selection of options in each of the groups, or when deleting a group, the list of options in the select should also change.

I presented all the code in `Stackblitz`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fpgc32?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,package.json,tsconfig.json,src%2Fglobal_styles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css&title=Angular%20Starter

UPD: Issue is solved